# How to open a location from executeable jar file

Tags: java, jar, location, runtime-error, executable-jar

I've written a java program which fetches the present directory using

```
URL location = FileToString.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

and am trying to open the same location using

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(location.getFile()));
```

It works fine,the location gets opened in a new window when I run it in eclipse.

But, When I export the same project to executable jar and run,It doesn't.

It shows an error like `could not find the main class,program will exit`

Below is the log in `cmd` when i run `java -verbose -jar <jarpath>`

```
[Loaded sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger$1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt
.jar]
[Loaded sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger$LoggerProxy from C:\Program Files\Java\j
re7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger$DefaultLoggerProxy from C:\Program Files
\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger$JavaLoggerProxy from C:\Program Files\Ja
va\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.util.logging.LoggingSupport from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.j
ar]
[Loaded sun.util.logging.LoggingSupport$1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt
.jar]
[Loaded sun.util.logging.LoggingProxy from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar
]
[Loaded java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\r
t.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\l
ib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.UnsafeQualifiedStaticFieldAccessorImpl from C:\Program Files
\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.UnsafeQualifiedStaticObjectFieldAccessorImpl from C:\Program
 Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.util.logging.LoggingSupport$2 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt
.jar]
[Loaded java.util.Date from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.util.calendar.CalendarSystem from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.
jar]
[Loaded sun.util.calendar.AbstractCalendar from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\r
t.jar]
[Loaded sun.util.calendar.BaseCalendar from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.ja
r]
[Loaded sun.util.calendar.Gregorian from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.Transparency from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.DisposerTarget from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.StateTrackable from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.Surface from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.SurfaceData from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.IllegalStateException from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.j
ar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.InvalidPipeException from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.j
ar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.NullSurfaceData from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.StateTrackable$State from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.j
ar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.loops.SurfaceType from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]

[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]

[Loaded java.lang.Integer$IntegerCache from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.ja
r]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$Xrgb from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt
.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$Argb from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt
.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$ArgbPre from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib
\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$Xbgr from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt
.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$Rgba from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt
.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$RgbaPre from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib
\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$Ushort565Rgb from C:\Program Files\Java\jre
7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$Ushort555Rgb from C:\Program Files\Java\jre
7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$Ushort555Rgbx from C:\Program Files\Java\jr
e7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$Ushort4444Argb from C:\Program Files\Java\j
re7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$ByteGray from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\li
b\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$UshortGray from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\
lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$Rgbx from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt
.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$Bgrx from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt
.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$ArgbBm from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\
rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.image.ColorModel from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.image.PackedColorModel from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.j
ar]
[Loaded java.awt.image.DirectColorModel from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.j
ar]
[Loaded java.awt.color.ColorSpace from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.color.ICC_Profile from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.cmm.ProfileDeferralInfo from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\r
t.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.cmm.ProfileDeferralMgr from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt
.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.color.ICC_ProfileRGB from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar
]
[Loaded sun.java2d.cmm.ProfileActivator from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.j
ar]
[Loaded java.awt.color.ICC_Profile$1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]

[Loaded java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar
]
[Loaded sun.java2d.StateTrackableDelegate from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt
.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.StateTrackableDelegate$2 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\
rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.PixelDrawPipe from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar
]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.PixelFillPipe from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar
]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.ShapeDrawPipe from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar
]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.TextPipe from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImagePipe from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar
]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.NullPipe from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.image.IndexColorModel from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.ja
r]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.ParallelogramPipe from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt
.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.LoopBasedPipe from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar
]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.LoopPipe from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.RenderingEngine from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.j
ar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.RenderingEngine$1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt
.jar]
[Loaded sun.dc.DuctusRenderingEngine from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]

[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.OutlineTextRenderer from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\
rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.GlyphListPipe from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar
]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.GlyphListLoopPipe from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt
.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.SolidTextRenderer from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt
.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.AATextRenderer from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.ja
r]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.LCDTextRenderer from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.j
ar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.CompositePipe from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar
]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.AlphaColorPipe from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.ja
r]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.PixelToShapeConverter from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\li
b\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.SurfaceData$PixelToShapeLoopConverter from C:\Program Files\J
ava\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.PixelToParallelogramConverter from C:\Program Files\Java
\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.SurfaceData$PixelToPgramLoopConverter from C:\Program Files\J
ava\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.TextRenderer from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]

[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.SpanClipRenderer from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.
jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.Region from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.RegionIterator from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.ja
r]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.Region$ImmutableRegion from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\l
ib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.AAShapePipe from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.AlphaPaintPipe from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.ja
r]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.SpanShapeRenderer from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt
.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.SpanShapeRenderer$Composite from C:\Program Files\Java\j
re7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.GeneralCompositePipe from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib
\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.loops.RenderCache from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]

[Loaded sun.java2d.loops.RenderCache$Entry from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\r
t.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.DestSurfaceProvider from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.ja
r]
[Loaded java.awt.Image from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.image.VolatileImage from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]

[Loaded sun.awt.image.SunVolatileImage from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.ja
r]
[Loaded java.awt.ImageCapabilities from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.SurfaceManager$ImageAccessor from C:\Program Files\Java\jr
e7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.Image$1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.SurfaceManager from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]

[Loaded java.util.EventListener from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.DisplayChangedListener from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.ja
r]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.VolatileSurfaceManager from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib
\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.image.ImageObserver from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]

[Loaded java.awt.MenuContainer from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.Component from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.ja
r]
[Loaded java.util.EventObject from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.AWTEvent from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.event.ComponentEvent from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar
]
[Loaded java.awt.event.InputEvent from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.AWTAccessor$AWTEventAccessor from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib
\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.AWTEvent$1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.AWTAccessor from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.event.NativeLibLoader from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.ja
r]
[Loaded sun.awt.AWTAccessor$InputEventAccessor from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\l
ib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.event.InputEvent$1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.peer.ComponentPeer from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.dnd.peer.DropTargetPeer from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.
jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WObjectPeer from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.ja
r]
[Loaded java.awt.Font from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.font.FontAccess from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.Font$FontAccessImpl from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]

[Loaded java.awt.geom.AffineTransform from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar
]
[Loaded sun.font.AttributeValues from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.font.EAttribute from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator$Attribute from C:\Program Files\Ja
va\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Class$4 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib
\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.font.TextAttribute from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.AWTAccessor$ComponentAccessor from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\li
b\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.Component$1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.RequestFocusController from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.ja
r]
[Loaded java.awt.Component$DummyRequestFocusController from C:\Program Files\Jav
a\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WToolkit$1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.
jar]
[Loaded java.awt.Toolkit$DesktopPropertyChangeSupport from C:\Program Files\Java
\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.beans.ChangeListenerMap from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]

[Loaded java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport$PropertyChangeListenerMap from C:\Progr
am Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.beans.PropertyChangeListener from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt
.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.ModalityListener from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.SunToolkit$ModalityListenerList from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\
lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.misc.PerformanceLogger from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.misc.PerformanceLogger$TimeData from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\
rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.DisposerRecord from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WToolkit$ToolkitDisposer from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.Disposer from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.Disposer$1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WToolkit$2 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WToolkit$2$1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]

[Loaded java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\r
t.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks$1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib
\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown$Lock from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.AppContext from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.misc.JavaAWTAccess from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.AppContext$6 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.AppContext$3 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.AppContext$2 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.AppContext$State from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.AppContext$1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.EventQueue from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.EventQueue$1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.AWTAccessor$EventQueueAccessor from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\l
ib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.EventQueue$2 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.Queue from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.MostRecentKeyValue from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.PostEventQueue from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.peer.DesktopPeer from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]

[Loaded java.awt.Desktop$Action from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap$KeySet from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.
jar]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap$IdentityHashMapIterator from C:\Program Files\
Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap$KeyIterator from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\li
b\rt.jar]
```

*(Note: Main class is present in manifest file,This error doesn't occurs if I remove Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(location.getFile())); from code and export executable jar)*

Few solutions for quite similar issues in stackOverflow says to read in InputStream.
Though  was not clear with the solution,I tried but din't work.

Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: And the URL that doesn't work looks like?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It shows an error like _**could not find the main class,program will exit_**

(Note: Main class is present in manifest file,This error doesn't occurs if I remove **Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(location.getFile()));** from code and export executable jar)

Comment: That is not a problem with your code but with your packaging.   You must reproduce the complete error message in your question in order to allow anybody to be able to help you.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen thanks for the suggestion. I'll certainly do that. But what could be the possible solution for this? Do I need make any changes at code level or packaging?

Comment: No idea, show the full output from invoking "java -verbose -jar ..." to help diagnosing.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen have edited the question with output involking "java -verbose -jar ...". It might help you to diagonise my issue,Please provide suggestions if you have any. Thank for the help :)

Comment: And this is from a _failing_ version?  Things look fine.

Comment: Yes,this is!. soon after this I get a error message **_could not find the main class,program will exit_**  like in a alert window but not printed on cmd and the location **Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(location.getFile()));** doesn't open.

Comment: Create a downloadable version of the failing jar.